# Windows Apps in 8.1 side-loading without a domain

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, windows, sideloading

I've developed a utility app to record video/audio for a client and want to side-load it on his machines. They are a small company and are not using Active Directory.

The app targets Windows 8.1 desktops only and DirectX 10+.

I have also submitted the app to the app store out of frustration but this is not a sustainable option. The objective is to test the app with specific capture hardware on the client's premises.

Any pointers on how to side-load on a Windows 8.1 Pro (without domain-join) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an installer, ran as administrator, that sets this reg key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx\AllowAllTrustedApps = 1
```

that should allow apps to be installed and then you can use powershell to install the app using the following command:

```
add-appxpackage file.appx
```

note: add-appxpackage only installs the app for the user account running powershell.

source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx